# How to get list of controller in frontend from backend in Yii2 Advanced Template?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I use metadata class to retrieve data but just only in frontend or backend. i don't know how to get data across from backend to frontend. Thank you very much.

Comment: if you use the same session for frontend / backend you can use session. other possibility would be links with get or post methods to change between them (depends on your requirement)

Comment: i use separate session with different main config, i don't know how to access all controller in apps frontend when write code in backend, can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `components`. It can work for an app (component folder in backend or frontend) or also you can create in common folder, so you could use for both. It's a good way to get maintainable code. 
More info: http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/how-to-create-custom-component-in-yii2-0-framework/

Comment: Can you explain more detail ?  How can i get  list of controller in frontend app when I write code in the backend controller that use  components, method such as getListController ( )...

Comment: @huyleuit the idea is to code a controller in common/components and use it in both apps